# The Worst Riley yet?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

My start is part of something you may slip inside a sock

My middle is infernal and you may wish to block

My ending denotes someone with a speciality

My whole describes the writer of this dreadful poetry.

**What am I?**

---

**Clue 1**

> A few people have got hung up on the word describing ME as the writer and seem to be Googling my nickname... the answer doesn't require any knowledge of my good self other than what is written in this poem.

**Clue 2**

> The first line is indeed referring to *part* of a foot, not another word for a foot.

**Clue 3**

> Shakespeare it ain't!

Comment: @NL628 I have rolled back your edits - firstly because I disagree with the use of "prefix" and "infix" in this style of puzzle because the way the answer is divided up often does not really fit the definition of word prefixes or suffixes. Secondly because you ruined the rhyme scheme

Comment: Oops, I apologize for doing so. I wanted to keep the Riley scheme, but now that you mentioned why you deviated, I totally understand. I apologize for that!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

> **Balladmonger**

*My start is part of something you may slip inside a sock*

> The **ball** of your foot

*My middle is infernal and you may wish to block*

> Every horrible pop-up **ad** that we have to block

*My ending denotes someone with a speciality*

> A **monger** is someone dealing in a specific commodity

*My whole describes the writer of this dreadful poetry*

> A balladmonger means an inferior poet. But you shouldn't sell yourself short. ;)

Comment: SO CLOSE! First and second parts correct.

Comment: @Astralbee Ah, thanks for the tip! Better now? ;)

Comment: Spot on! Congratulations.

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer for the middle:

> dam
>
>  The word *damn* is related to infernal and the word *dam* is a synonym of block

Comment: Infernal = hell

Comment: Very clever but not right sadly - on this occasion synonymous means "closely associated with" if that helps? I'll drop some clues tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

> I think the fist word is ped- or pod-, which are root words for foot. You put your feet or foot in a sock. The word ends in -ist, which is a root word for specialty . I'm not sure about the middle word, so the word kinda looks like ped--ist, or pod--ist

Thanks to Gustavo, the answer is

> Pedamist, which also seems like a twitter account

Comment: When I saw your answer, I thought about pedamist or podamist but didn't find them as real words. So I thought that was not it...

Comment: Idk. Pedamist seems like a twitter account

Comment: Good effort but sadly no parts are correct.

Comment: Intrigued why you think the final answer is a Twitter account?

Comment: @Astralbee Idk maybe that was your twitter account "My whole describes the writer of this dreadful poetry

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> a hole-puncher?

First:

> holes are often found in socks

Second:

> you might want to block a punch. Not sure what would make it infernal though...

Third:

> an "ER" doctor is a specialist in emergency medicine.

Comment: Another great answer that deserves a +1 - you are on the right kind of thinking with the second part, but incorrect. And I have added a clue about the first part.

Comment: @Astralbee dang. That means it's probably not "toe-tally _____" either.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Bridgeable?

Explanation:

Start:

> Bridge is part of the foot

Middle:

> ridge is like a block, going over the edge is going to hell.

End:

> Someone with a specialty is "Able"

Whole:

> Bridgeable could be interpreted to mean humble. The author is being humble when calling their poetry bad, and their puzzle the "worst"

Comment: Not right, but best answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Too Damn Smart?

First:

> Toe, which you could slur to "too"

Second:

> Dam and damn, per @GustavoGabriel. This also suggests we're looking at homophones, which plays to the first part.

Third:

> Someone with a specialty might be "smart" on their area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

### Partial answer for first

> Current best thought is "arch," which could be an intensifier for the second bit (e.g. arch-fiend)